# WooCommerce - dynamically loading checkout page using ajax not showing payment methods for guest

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224595/woocommerce-how-can-i-dynamically-load-checkout-page-using-ajax) answer on how to dynamically load checkout page using ajax in Woocommerce.

when using this js/php code to get the checkout page fragment

1.If im logged in it works fine and the defined payment methods (Paypal, bank transfer, checks) are showing up (OK)

2.for guest users, im getting the error:
**"Sorry, it seems that there are no available payment methods for your state"**

```
/* PHP Code on functions.php */
add_action( 'wp_ajax_getCheckoutPageContent', 'getCheckoutPageContentCallBack' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_getCheckoutPageContent', 'getCheckoutPageContentCallBack' );

function getCheckoutPageContentCallBack() {

    define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT', true );
    echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_checkout]'); 

    die();
}

/* JS Code to be called on callback*/
var wp_ajax_url="http://yourwebsite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
var data = {
    action: 'getCheckoutPageContent'
};

jQuery.post( wp_ajax_url, data, function(content) {
    // append content to my custom one page checkout 
});
```

i tried to add this filter

```
// this is used for taxing:
add_filter('woocommerce_countries_base_country', 'set_base_to_usercountry', 1, 1);

// and this is used for shipping:
add_filter('woocommerce_customer_default_location', 'set_base_to_usercountry', 1, 1);

function set_base_to_usercountry($country) {
    $country = MYCOUNTRYCODE; 
    return $country;
}
```

but this didnt help.
Any ideas how to fix this ?
Thank you

Comment: I'd guess this is for the U.S. but I don't know exactly when it's triggered. The next line of the error is "Please fill in your details above to see available payment methods". Does this happen even when you've chosen a state?

Comment: But the actual in-code problem is that $available_gateways is empty. Can you debug why they're not getting set up for unauthenticated users? I'd guess your authenticated users do have state and country selected and saved somewhere. It's also possible that $available_gateways isn't being set up properly by the AJAX mechanism you're using so you'd need to debug that.

Comment: (That all said, you'd probably do better asking somewhere where there are more WooCommerce experts - it's technically off-topic here, even though we do have some old questions and answers.)

Comment: Hi @Rup, 
i dont know why $available_gateways is empty. i tried to add nonce in my Ajax call.
anyway, im going to try the Woocomerce slack group.

Comment: @buzibuzi did you solve this problem ?

Comment: @g-f - no i didnt solve it